# WP add_filter using concatenation and echo to call WP function - WP function displays as text only

Tags: php, wordpress, add-filter

Attempting to add content to existing posts via an add_filter. Filter includes html and three WP function calls using echo. Add_filter works but displays the echoed functions as text only.
Appreciate any help, direction or advice.

```
add_filter ('the_content', 'insertAuthorMetaData');
function insertAuthorMetaData($content) {
if(is_single()) {
$content.= '<div id="content" class="author-meta-info">';
$content.= '<hr/>';
$content.= '<h4 class="avatar-in-loop">';
$content.= '<h4 class="avatar-in-loop">';
$content.= '<h4 class="avatar-in-loop">';
$content.= '</h4>';
$content.= '<dl><dt></dt><dd>';
$content.= echo the_author_meta( 'description' );
$content.= ' </dd></dl><hr />';
$content.= '</div>';
 }
return $content;
}
```

thank you.
bobp

Comment: how do you expect us to be able to help with ANYTHING if you don't post relevant code?

Comment: -1, @celeriko says. We can help you if you posting **nothing**?

Comment: you dont need to `echo` if you are using string concatenation operator (`.=`), just do `$content .= the_author_meta('description');`

Comment: also, the html you are returning is invalid.  you will end up with two unclosed `<h4>` tags

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't echo inside a filter. A filter's job is to modify the content rather than output something. Also you're using `the_author_meta()` which outputs the meta when you need a function that will return it. You need to use `get_the_author_meta()` instead.

Change this:

```
$content.= echo the_author_meta( 'description' );
```

To:

```
$content .= get_the_author_meta( 'description' );
```

Comment: Works exactly as needed. Thanks for responding and explaining-bobp